# How to increase performance of the query which counts the records by a specific time interval?

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

I use a PostgreSQL 9.5. Below you can find a structure of my table, my query and a result of the query. I would like to increase performance of my query. The query counts the records by a specific time interval, for example: `250 milliseconds`, `1 second`, `22 minutes`, `2 days and 30 minutes`, etc.

The query is fast for the large intervals like `60 minutes` but for the small intervals like `4 seconds` it's very slow.

The most important things:

- I work with a large database (20 million rows and more but in query I use a part of this database using `WHERE` clause, for example: 1 million or more).
- There are always the `id_user_table` and `sip` columns in the `WHERE` clause. In some cases, the `WHERE` clause colud include all of the columns of the table, it depends on the user's choice.
- At the moment I've created a B-Tree index on the `starttime` column:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX starttime_interval ON data_store (starttime);
  ```

**Do you know some ways to increase performance of my query?**

For example, by means of:

- creating some indexes on the columns (which indexes? and how to create them?),
- improving my query,
- changing some settings in the PostgreSQL,
- or somethings else.

Here's the structure of my table:

```
  column_name  |   udt_name  | length | is_nullable |  key
---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+--------
id             |    int8     |        |     NO      |   PK
id_user_table  |    int4     |        |     NO      |   FK
starttime      | timestamptz |        |     NO      |
time           |   float8    |        |     NO      |
sip            |   varchar   |  100   |     NO      |
dip            |   varchar   |  100   |     NO      |
sport          |    int4     |        |     YES     |
dport          |    int4     |        |     YES     |
proto          |   varchar   |   50   |     NO      |
totbytes       |    int8     |        |     YES     |
info           |    text     |        |     YES     |
label          |   varchar   |   10   |     NO      |
```

Simple `SELECT * FROM data_Store WHERE id_user_table=1 and sip='147.32.84.138' ORDER BY starttime` returns this:

```
  id | id_user_table |          starttime         |      sip      |  other columns...
-----+---------------+----------------------------+---------------+--------------------
 185 |       1       | 2011-09-12 15:24:03.248+02 | 147.32.84.138 |        ...
 189 |       1       | 2011-09-12 15:24:03.256+02 | 147.32.84.138 |        ...
 312 |       1       | 2011-09-12 15:24:06.112+02 | 147.32.84.138 |        ...
 313 |       1       | 2011-09-12 15:24:06.119+02 | 147.32.84.138 |        ... 
 450 |       1       | 2011-09-12 15:24:09.196+02 | 147.32.84.138 |        ...
 451 |       1       | 2011-09-12 15:24:09.203+02 | 147.32.84.138 |        ... 
 452 |       1       | 2011-09-12 15:24:09.21+02  | 147.32.84.138 |        ...
```

Here's my query for the 4 seconds time intervals:

```
WITH generate_period AS(

    SELECT generate_series(date_trunc('second',min(starttime)), 
                           date_trunc('second',max(starttime)), 
                           interval '4 second') as tp
    FROM data_store 
    WHERE id_user_table=1 and sip='147.32.84.138' --other restrictions

), data_series AS(

    SELECT date_trunc('second', starttime) AS starttime, count(*) AS ct
    FROM data_store  
    WHERE id_user_table=1 and sip='147.32.84.138' --other restrictions
    GROUP  BY 1

)

SELECT gp.tp AS starttime-from, 
       gp.tp + interval '4 second' AS starttime-to, 
       COALESCE(sum(ds.ct),0) AS ct
FROM  generate_period gp
LEFT JOIN data_series ds ON date_trunc('second',ds.starttime) >= gp.tp 
                        and date_trunc('second',ds.starttime) < gp.tp + interval '4 second'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Here's the result of the query:

```
      starttime-from    |      starttime-to      |   ct
------------------------+------------------------+---------
 2011-09-12 15:24:03+02 | 2011-09-12 15:24:07+02 |    4
 2011-09-12 15:24:07+02 | 2011-09-12 15:24:11+02 |    3
 2011-09-12 15:24:11+02 | 2011-09-12 15:24:15+02 |    0
           ...          |           ...          |   ...
```

Here's the result of the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` which I received in the pgAdmin for the 4 seconds time intervals:

```
Sort  (cost=7477837.88..7477838.38 rows=200 width=16) (actual time=1537280.238..1537289.519 rows=60141 loops=1)
  Sort Key: gp.tp
  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1792kB
  CTE generate_period
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=166919.73..166924.74 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=752.301..823.022 rows=60141 loops=1)
          ->  Seq Scan on data_store  (cost=0.00..163427.57 rows=698431 width=8) (actual time=0.034..703.845 rows=679951 loops=1)
                Filter: ((id_user_table = 1) AND ((sip)::text = '147.32.84.138'::text))
                Rows Removed by Filter: 4030687
  CTE data_series
    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=242521.00..250085.18 rows=186076 width=8) (actual time=1233.414..1341.701 rows=57555 loops=1)
          Group Key: (date_trunc('second'::text, data_store_1.starttime))
          ->  Sort  (cost=242521.00..244267.08 rows=698431 width=8) (actual time=1233.407..1284.110 rows=679951 loops=1)
                Sort Key: (date_trunc('second'::text, data_store_1.starttime))
                Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 11960kB
                ->  Seq Scan on data_store data_store_1  (cost=0.00..165173.65 rows=698431 width=8) (actual time=0.043..886.224 rows=679951 loops=1)
                      Filter: ((id_user_table = 1) AND ((sip)::text = '147.32.84.138'::text))
                      Rows Removed by Filter: 4030687
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=7060817.31..7060820.31 rows=200 width=16) (actual time=1537215.586..1537240.698 rows=60141 loops=1)
        Group Key: gp.tp
        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..6957441.76 rows=20675111 width=16) (actual time=1985.731..1536921.862 rows=74443 loops=1)
              Join Filter: ((date_trunc('second'::text, ds.starttime) >= gp.tp) AND (date_trunc('second'::text, ds.starttime) < (gp.tp + '00:00:04'::interval)))
              Rows Removed by Join Filter: 3461357700
              ->  CTE Scan on generate_period gp  (cost=0.00..20.00 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=752.303..910.810 rows=60141 loops=1)
              ->  CTE Scan on data_series ds  (cost=0.00..3721.52 rows=186076 width=16) (actual time=0.021..3.716 rows=57555 loops=60141)
Planning time: 0.258 ms
Execution time: 1537389.102 ms
```

## Update

Here's the another query but without `WITH cte` and `date_trunc()` expression so maybe this query will be easier to optimize:

```
SELECT gp.tp AS starttime_from, 
       gp.tp + interval '4 second' AS starttime_to, 
       count(ds.id)
FROM (SELECT generate_series(min(starttime), max(starttime), interval '4 second') as tp
      FROM data_store
      WHERE id_user_table=1 and sip='147.32.84.138' --other restrictions
     ) gp
     LEFT JOIN data_store ds 
     ON ds.starttime >= gp.tp and ds.starttime < gp.tp + interval '4 second'
        and id_user_table=1 and sip='147.32.84.138' --other restrictions
group by gp.tp
order by gp.tp;
```

The above query is much faster than the first query. At the moment B-Tree index on `starttime` column works but it's still not enough. If I set the `100 milliseconds` time intervals, I've to still wait too long. The `100 milliseconds` range is the minimal time interval which the user can set. I've just added B-Tree index on `sip` column but it doesn't help.

Here's the result of the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` which I received in the pgAdmin for the 100 ms time intervals:

```
Sort  (cost=14672356.96..14672357.46 rows=200 width=16) (actual time=9380.768..9951.074 rows=2405621 loops=1)
  Sort Key: (generate_series(date_trunc('second'::text, $0), date_trunc('second'::text, $1), '00:00:00.1'::interval))
  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 79880kB
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=14672346.81..14672349.31 rows=200 width=16) (actual time=6199.538..7232.962 rows=2405621 loops=1)
        Group Key: (generate_series(date_trunc('second'::text, $0), date_trunc('second'::text, $1), '00:00:00.1'::interval))
        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=2.02..14284329.59 rows=77603444 width=16) (actual time=0.321..4764.648 rows=3006226 loops=1)
              ->  Result  (cost=1.58..6.59 rows=1000 width=0) (actual time=0.295..159.147 rows=2405621 loops=1)
                    InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
                      ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..0.79 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.208..0.208 rows=1 loops=1)
                            ->  Index Scan using starttime_interval on data_store  (cost=0.43..250437.98 rows=698431 width=8) (actual time=0.204..0.204 rows=1 loops=1)
                                  Index Cond: (starttime IS NOT NULL)
                                  Filter: ((id_user_table = 1) AND ((sip)::text = '147.32.84.138'::text))
                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 144
                    InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
                      ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..0.79 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.050..0.050 rows=1 loops=1)
                            ->  Index Scan Backward using starttime_interval on data_store data_store_1  (cost=0.43..250437.98 rows=698431 width=8) (actual time=0.049..0.049 rows=1 loops=1)
                                  Index Cond: (starttime IS NOT NULL)
                                  Filter: ((id_user_table = 1) AND ((sip)::text = '147.32.84.138'::text))
                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 23
              ->  Index Scan using starttime_interval on data_store ds  (cost=0.44..13508.28 rows=77603 width=16) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=2405621)
                    Index Cond: ((starttime >= (generate_series(date_trunc('second'::text, $0), date_trunc('second'::text, $1), '00:00:00.1'::interval))) AND (starttime < ((generate_series(date_trunc('second'::text, $0), date_trunc('second'::text, $1), '00 (...)
                    Filter: ((id_user_table = 1) AND ((sip)::text = '147.32.84.138'::text))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 2
Planning time: 1.299 ms
Execution time: 11641.154 ms
```

Comment: you forgot to post your explain analyze

Comment: 1st note: CTEs act as optimization barriers in PostgreSQL: `data_series` will work like a temp table, querying it won't use indexes of `data_store`; 2nd. note: if you use an expression like `date_trunc('second', starttime)` in `WHERE` or join condition, it won't use the plain `starttime` index neither (and you can't index the `date_trunc('second', starttime)` expression if I remember well: it's not immutable -- at least the undocumented one, which uses `timestamptz` arguments)

Comment: @pozs, thanks for your advices, I've just updated my post. I've added another query without `WITH cte` and `date_trunc` expression and now the B-Tree index on the `starttime` column works. The new query is executed much faster but I need something faster, if it's possiable.

Comment: You can try to remove the `order by gp.tp` too (`generate_series()` should give the results already in ascending order -- no guarantee though). This last example you gave uses a really a small density, I wonder how many zero count rows it contains. I'm afraid those will eat up space (connection transfer time) & computation time. You could try to remove those rows (e.g. with `having count(ds.id) > 0`) & handle empty/zero logic on the client side.

Comment: Unfortunately when I removed the `order by gp.tp`, the result wasn't sorted but when I moved the `order by gp.tp` to the subquery where the `generate_series()` is - the result was sorted and the query was executed faster. The answer to your question about `How many zero are there` is: the smaller the time interval and the units, the more zeros. When I added the `having count(ds.id) > 0` restriction, the query for the 100 ms time intervals was executed extremely quickly (in few seconds). It seems that I'll have to think about the handle of `0` on the client side. Thanks for your advices again!

Comment: I'd try with `CREATE INDEX my_index ON data_store (id_user_table, sip, starttime);`

Comment: @RadekPostołowicz, it's very nice! For the very small time intervals (~100 ms) the query is executed in the same time or a little longer BUT for a little bigger time intervals (>1 second), the query is executed much faster. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the @pozs and @RadekPostołowicz comments, the final query is as follows (for the 4 seconds time intervals):

```
SELECT gp.tp AS starttime_from, gp.tp + interval '4 second' AS starttime_to, count(ds.id)
FROM (SELECT generate_series(min(starttime),max(starttime), interval '4 second') as tp
      FROM data_store
      WHERE id_user_table=1 and sip='147.32.84.138'
      ORDER BY 1
     ) gp 
     LEFT JOIN data_store ds 
     ON ds.id_user_table=1 and ds.sip='147.32.84.138' 
        and ds.starttime >= gp.tp and ds.starttime < gp.tp + interval '4 second'
GROUP BY starttime_from
```

As @pozs noticed, for the very small time intervals, the result of the query includes a lot of zero count rows. These rows eat up space. In this case the query should include the `HAVING count(ds.id) > 0` restriction but then you've to handle of these `0` on the client side. Here's the second version of the query which includes the `HAVING` restriction:

```
SELECT gp.tp AS starttime_from, gp.tp + interval '4 second' AS starttime_to, count(ds.id)
FROM (SELECT generate_series(min(starttime),max(starttime), interval '4 second') as tp
      FROM data_store
      WHERE id_user_table=1 and sip='147.32.84.138'
      ORDER BY 1
     ) gp 
     LEFT JOIN data_store ds 
     ON ds.id_user_table=1 and ds.sip='147.32.84.138' 
        and ds.starttime >= gp.tp and ds.starttime < gp.tp + interval '4 second'
GROUP BY starttime_from
HAVING count(ds.id) > 0
```

The most important thing is creating the multicolumn index which @RadekPostołowicz has created in his comment/answer:

```
CREATE INDEX my_index ON data_store (id_user_table, sip, starttime);
```

Why these columns? Because in each query I always use the `id_user_table`, the `sip` and the `starttime` columns in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

As I already wrote in comment you can using multicolumn index:

```
CREATE INDEX my_index ON data_store (id_user_table, sip, starttime);
```

This should remove `Filter: ((id_user_table = 1) AND ((sip)::text = '147.32.84.138'::text))` from your execution plan (and since every such a filter is executed in loop savings might be quite high).

I've also prepared alternative query:

```
select
    min + (max - min) * (least - 1) as starttime_from,
    min + (max - min) * least as starttime_to,
    count
from (
    select
        min,
        max,
        count(1),
        least(
            width_bucket(
                extract(epoch from starttime)::double precision,
                extract(epoch from min)::double precision,
                extract(epoch from max)::double precision,
                ceil(extract(epoch from (max - min))/extract(epoch from query_interval))::integer
            ),
            ceil(extract(epoch from (max - min))/extract(epoch from query_interval))::integer
        )
    from (
        select
            *,
            max(starttime) over (),
            min(starttime) over (),
            '4 second'::interval as query_interval
        from data_store
    ) as subquery2
    group by least, min, max
) as subquery1;
```

It should avoid nested loop and I guess it could be much faster. However it might need some adjustment to fit your desired result (some date truncation?).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried to run your query but I've received a strange result. There isn't the 4 seconds time interval, there is exactly the 20 min and 35 sec time interval. I'm not sure why. At the moment I don't have enough time to analyze your query deeper but I'll do that later. Before I do that, I'll stay with the query which I've put in my answer.

Comment: Interesting, if you share some test data which causes 20 min and 35 sec time interval (on sqlfiddle) I'll inspect it. Anyway don't feel forced to this, I understand that your problem is solved and you might not want to spend more time on it ;).